# I have to convert spark dataframe to nested json structure

Tags: json, pyspark

I'm trying to convert below dataframe into nested json and write to json file.

```
|       Trans_Type   |Payment_Due_Dt|BILL_CYCLE_ID|BALANCE_AMT|
+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+
|  New Transaction   |    26-01-2015|   31-12-2014|      61.20|
|Current Transactions|    26-01-2015|   31-12-2014|     289.02|
|  Age Transaction   |              |             |       0.00|
|Clear Transaction   |              |             |       0.00|
|      Remittances   |              |             |     -61.20|
+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+
```

```
spark_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- Trans_Type: string (nullable = false)
 |-- Payment_Due_Dt: string (nullable = true)
 |-- BILL_CYCLE_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- BALANCE_AMT: decimal(25,2) (nullable = false)
```

Account Balance is calculated as sum(balance_amt) = 647.00
Expected Json O/p -

```
{
    "Summary": [{
            "Age Transactions": {
                "Payment_Due_Dt": " ",
                "BILL_CYCLE_ID": " ",
                "BALANCE_AMT": 0.00
            }
        },
        {
            "Clear Transactions": {
                "Payment_Due_Dt": " ",
                "BILL_CYCLE_ID": " ",
                "BALANCE_AMT": 0.00
            }
        },
        {
            "Current Transactions": {
                "Payment_Due_Dt": "26-01-2015",
                "BILL_CYCLE_ID": "31-12-2014",
                "BALANCE_AMT": 289.02
            }
        },
        {
            "New Transactions": {
                "Payment_Due_Dt": "26-01-2015",
                "BILL_CYCLE_ID": "31-12-2014",
                "BALANCE_AMT": 61.20
            }   
        },
        {
            "Remittances" : {
                "BALANCE_AMT": 61.20
            }
            
        },
        {
            "Account Balance": {
            "BAL_AM": "647.00"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

With this code snippet , I was not able to get the desired o/p

```
list1 = [Txn_Sum_base2_DF["Payment_Due_Dt"], Txn_Sum_base2_DF["BILL_CYCLE_ID"], Txn_Sum_base2_DF["BALANCE_AMT"] ]
df = Txn_Sum_base2_DF.groupBy("Trans_Type") \
            .agg(collect_list(struct(list1)).alias("summary")).toJSON().collect()
```

the above code is giving me json structure but it's not matching with result.

Answer (score 0):

i was able to do this little differently. first, i create structs for the attributes, and then pivoted them with transaction type as columns. then, i created a struct with all transactions, which will be the `summary` field. the `account_balance` is a sum (as mentioned in the question), so i created a dataframe with the sum and joined it (*this could also be done using `aggregate` and `transform`*).

here's the approach using your sample data *(please adapt it to your specifications)*

```py
data1_sdf = data_sdf. \
    withColumn('attr', func.struct('pay_due_dt', 'bill_cycle_id', 'bal_amt')). \
    groupBy(func.lit(1).alias('dropme')). \
    pivot('trans_type'). \
    agg(func.first('attr'))

# +------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------+
# |dropme|Age Transaction  |Clear Transaction|Current Transactions            |New Transaction               |Remittances        |
# +------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------+
# |1     |{null, null, 0.0}|{null, null, 0.0}|{26-01-2015, 31-12-2014, 289.02}|{26-01-2015, 31-12-2014, 61.2}|{null, null, -61.2}|
# +------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------+

# calculate account balance
data2_sdf = data_sdf. \
    select(func.sum('bal_amt').alias('acc_bal'), func.lit(1).alias('dropme'))

# +-------+------+
# |acc_bal|dropme|
# +-------+------+
# | 289.02|     1|
# +-------+------+

# create final source for json
fnl_data_sdf = data1_sdf. \
    join(data2_sdf, ['dropme'], 'left'). \
    drop('dropme'). \
    withColumn('summary', func.struct(*data1_sdf.drop('dropme').columns))
```

now, there are 2 options. you could either create a field with json string using `to_json()`/`toJSON()` or write the `summary` and `acc_bal` fields as json.

```py
# using toJSON() to create json string
fnl_data_sdf. \
    select('summary', 'acc_bal'). \
    toJSON(). \
    collect()[0]

# '{"summary":{"Age Transaction":{"bal_amt":0.0},"Clear Transaction":{"bal_amt":0.0},"Current Transactions":{"pay_due_dt":"26-01-2015","bill_cycle_id":"31-12-2014","bal_amt":289.02},"New Transaction":{"pay_due_dt":"26-01-2015","bill_cycle_id":"31-12-2014","bal_amt":61.2},"Remittances":{"bal_amt":-61.2}},"acc_bal":289.02}'

# writing json files
fnl_data_sdf. \
    select('summary', 'acc_bal'). \
    coalesce(1). \
    write.json('/content/drive/MyDrive/json_output', mode='overwrite')
```